# how to find strings in DOM and change them by php or jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a text in html like this :

```
<blockquote>
    <p>
        Je suis un gros [b][u]Zéro[/u][/b], et pourtant j'ai [i]tout appris[/i] sur http://www.siteduzero.com<br />
        Je vous [b][color=green]recommande[/color][/b] d'aller sur ce site, vous pourrez apprendre à faire ça [i][color=purple]vous aussi[/color][/i] !
        [img]zozor_404.png[/img]
    </p>
</blockquote>
```

What I want is, in the `<p>` :

- find each **" [ "** then add `<b>` before it,
- find each **" ] "** then add `</b>` after it,

which makes the html like :

```
Je suis un gros <b>[b]</b><b>[u]</b>Zéro<b>[/u]</b><b>[/b]</b> ...
```

Seems like jQuery can do it by `$map()`, PHP can do it by `preg_match()`

Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: If it's that a simple rule, you can even use a str_replace (while preg_match is preferred - just read the manual & about regex patterns in the PHP offical website for better understanding on how it works).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

https://jsfiddle.net/aed9f1yo/

```
(function($){

    $(function(){
        'use strict';

        var $blockQuote = $('blockquote p'),
          text = $blockQuote.html(),
          result = text
                      .replace(/(\[)/ig, '<b>$1')
                      .replace(/(\])/ig, '$1</b>')

        $blockQuote.html(result);
    });
}(jQuery));
```

**Edit**

A little less code: https://jsfiddle.net/aed9f1yo/3/

Comment: Thanks, this works well. Only one question : why `/(\[.*?\])/ig` needs to put `*` and `?` together? Cause `*` means 0, 1 or unlimited times, which should match `[u]` or `[/u]`, but I tried this, it won't take `[/u]`, why?

Comment: You need to escape certain characters, like `[` or `/`. `?` is not make it "
"greedy".

Comment: putting " \ " before is already for escaping the special charaters, in this case, we already escapt `[` and `]`, and when there is no `?`, the regex is "greedy"(desire much more for what?), when there is `?`, the regex is "lazy"(lazy for what?), thanks for your patience.

Comment: I don't really understand your question I think. If you make the regex greedy, it will grab everything between the first `[` and the last `]`, see https://jsfiddle.net/aed9f1yo/4/.

Comment: I tried the regex without `?`, like this : `/(\[.*\])/ig`, it grabs only `[b]`, `[u]`, but neither `[/b]` nor `[/u]`, when I add `?`, it works. So you told me that adding `?` is to escape certain characters, but " \ " is already did it, that's why I don't understand `?` here, it double the escape function. And I never seen putting 2 quantifiers together, so when they are together, the regex become "lazy" so that it can grab each paire of "[ ]", not the first "[" and the last "]", is that right?

Answer (score 0):

Your JS (jQuery) file code could look something like this:

```
// Gets text from p
var myText = $("p").text()
// Splits text into array
var myTextSplit = myText.split("");
// Copy array of splits into new one so we can manipulate
var myDesiredText = myTextSplit.slice()
// Create a final output variable
var output = ""
// Offset additions variable - for loop
var additions = 0
// For loop to create output text
$(myTextSplit).each(function(index, element){
    if (element == "[") {
        myDesiredText.splice(index + additions, 0, "<b>");
        additions++
    }
    if (element == "]") {
        myDesiredText.splice(index + 1 + additions, 0, "</b>");
        additions++
    }
    // We also need to check when the loop is done to join array into text
    if (index == myTextSplit.length - 1 ) {
        output = myDesiredText.join("")
        // Change text to output
        $("p").text(output)
    }
})
```